# Can we use multiple rendered queryset in template with multiple for loops in scriptlet in Django framework?

Tags: django-templates

I am trying to fetch 2 tables data in a template using the querysets I rendered from my views.py, now I want to fetch both queryset in a template using scriptlet for loop in select field but it is not working. One select field in the template is showing the data but second select field is not showing the data. I tried and find that only one at a time is showing the data while 2nd is not working.

This is my views.py :

```
def assignWork(request):
    man=Coordinator.objects.filter(designation="Manager")
    t=Task.objects.all()
    return render(request,"MyAdmin/assignWork.html",{"key2":t},{"key1":man})
```

This is my template assignWork.html in which I am trying to use both.

```
 <form action="assignTask" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <label> Tasks</label>
    <br>
    <select required="">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    {% if key2 %}
    {% for var1 in key2 %}
    <option value="{{ var.id}}">
    {{ var1.company.cname }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    </select>
    <br>
    <label> Manager</label>
    <br>
    <select name=txtname required="">
    <option value="">Select Manager</option>
    {% if key1 %}
    {% for var in key1 %}

    <option>
    {{ var.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    </select> 
    <a href="ownerdash"><b> <- Back</b></a>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit Details">
    </form>
```